# Deploying WAR files to Tomcat in Jenkins

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins

WAR file that is generated by “my_website_pakaging” (this is upstream project that is executed without error), however in downstream project I want to deploy this war file to Tomcat container
the configuration is as follows

[image: configuration to deploy on Tomcat]

tomcat-user.xml has the following configuration:

[image: tomcat-user.xml configuration]

However, I am getting following error

[image: error output]

Tomcat server is working fine

[image: Tomcat server]

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

below is the full console output:

for the upstream project "my_website_packaging"

```
     Started by user Sanju000
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/sandeep000/maven-project.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/sandeep000/maven-project.git
> git --version # timeout=10
> git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/sandeep000/maven-project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 746f48a40a46370c0fa3609127f7ececab47f2f4 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f 746f48a40a46370c0fa3609127f7ececab47f2f4
Commit message: "updates from checksum"
> git rev-list 746f48a40a46370c0fa3609127f7ececab47f2f4 # timeout=10
[my_website_packaging] $ /home/jenkins/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin/mvn clean package checkstyle:checkstyle
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.maven-project:server:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.maven-project:webapp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.maven-project:maven-project:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter. @ line 51,     column 24
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] The project com.example.maven-project:maven-project:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not     for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-    rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Maven Project
[INFO] Server
[INFO] Webapp
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ maven-project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.8:checkstyle (default-cli) @ maven-project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Server 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ server ---
[INFO] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/server/target
[ INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ server ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/server/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ server ---
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/server/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ server ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/server/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ server ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/server/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.11:test (default-test) @ server ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/server/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.example.TestGreeter
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.592 sec

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ server ---
[INFO] Building jar: 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/server/target/server.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.8:checkstyle (default-cli) @ server ---
[INFO] 
[WARNING] Unable to locate Source XRef to link to - DISABLED
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Building Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Deleting 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/webapp/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ webapp 
---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/webapp/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ webapp --
-
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) 
@ webapp ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/webapp/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ 
webapp ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.11:test (default-test) @ webapp ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/webapp/target/surefire-
reports

-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [webapp] in 
[/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/webapp/target/webapp]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources 
[/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/webapp/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [206 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/webapp/target/webapp.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.8:checkstyle (default-cli) @ webapp ---
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Maven Project ...................................... SUCCESS [  9.377 
s]
[INFO] Server ............................................. SUCCESS [ 26.852 
s]
[INFO] Webapp ............................................. SUCCESS [  5.206 
s]
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Total time: 46.936 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-08T15:55:25Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/77M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[CHECKSTYLE] Collecting checkstyle analysis files...
[CHECKSTYLE] Searching for all files in 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging that match the pattern 
**/checkstyle-result.xml
[CHECKSTYLE] Parsing 1 file in 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging
[CHECKSTYLE] Successfully parsed file 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging/server/target/checkstyle-
result.xml with 0 unique warnings and 0 duplicates.
<Git Blamer> Using GitBlamer to create author and commit information for all 
warnings.
<Git Blamer> GIT_COMMIT=746f48a40a46370c0fa3609127f7ececab47f2f4, 
workspace=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_packaging
[CHECKSTYLE] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #62
Archiving artifacts
Triggering a new build of my_website_deploy_to_staging
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Now for the downstream project "my_website_deploy_to_staging"

```
 Started by upstream project "my_website_packaging" build number 63
 originally caused by:
 Started by user Sanju000
 Building in workspace 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_deploy_to_staging
 Copied 1 artifact from "my_website_packaging" build number 63

    Deploying /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_deploy_to_staging/webapp/target/webapp.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote with context 
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_website_deploy_to_staging/webapp/target/webapp.war]
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:192)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:998)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:976)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:736)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:682)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:627)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1762)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:561)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:876)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:889)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:173)
... 17 more
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:561)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:876)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:889)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:173)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:998)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:976)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:736)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:682)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:627)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1762)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: You need to show the whole stack trace. The reason is in the bottom.

Comment: Hi Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, I have added the whole stack trace, please have a look, thank you!

Comment: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)` - the address cargo tries to use to reach Tomcat is wrong.

Comment: the address is http://sanju0001.mylabserver.com:8090/, this is public address and active, why Jenkins is having problem to connect with this?

Comment: Can Jenkins reach the needed port across the network?  You can test on the Jenkins host by telnetting to the server and port.

Comment: Both Jenkins and Tomcat are on same server, Jenkins uses  sanju0001.mylabserver.com:8080 and Tomcat uses  sanju0001.mylabserver.com:8090

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right format to telnet:[jenkins@sanju0001]$ telnet http://sanju0001.mylabserver.com:8090/
telnet: http://sanju0001.mylabserver.com:8090/: Name or service not known
http://sanju0001.mylabserver.com:8090/: Unknown host

Comment: `telnet  sanju0001.mylabserver.com 8090`

Comment: I tried both 8080 and 8090 port  [jenkins@sanju0001 ~]$ telnet sanju0001.mylabserver.com 8090
Trying 34.238.XXX.XXX...
telnet: connect to address 34.238.XXX.XXX: Connection timed out
[jenkins@sanju0001 ~]$ telnet sanju0001.mylabserver.com 8080
Trying 34.238.XXX.XXX...
telnet: connect to address 34.238.XXX.XXX: Connection timed out

Comment: Find out why and fix it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing in the right direction, I replaced http://sanju0001.mylabserver.com:8090 with http://localhost:8090 and deployment is a success now. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not configured Cargo correctly - the connection timed out indicate that you are trying to access an IP-number which for some reason is not fully reachable from your current host.  This can have many causes - network routing is complicated especially if NAT-routers are involved - but is usually fixed by configuring Cargo to use a reachable network address instead.  In this particular case, use  `localhost:8090` instead.

A good diagnostic tool is

```
telnet host port
```

which lets you see easily if a network connection can be done to a specific port.  If telnet is not available, netcat may be:

```
nc -v host port
```

(See https://scottlinux.com/2013/12/19/stop-using-telnet-and-start-using-netcat/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen for pointing out "the address cargo tries to use to reach Tomcat is wrong". When your Jenkins and Tomcat are hosted in the same machine, then under deploy war/ear to a container enter Tomcat URL as "http://localhost:tomcat_port" e.g "http://localhost:8090" instead of some fancy hostname (sanju0001.mylabserver.com:8090). This will prevent connection error issue (due to not proper configuration of local DNS)